# Upgrading a computer with having only two options: RAM or CPU?

Tags: performance, upgrade

I have a computer and I want to upgrade it with the least costs and get the best performance consequently which way is the best? upgrading RAM or CPU? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you using the computer for, gaming, word processing, video editing...?

Comment: Without knowing how much RAM or what CPU it currently has makes it difficult to give an opinion on what will make the machine faster.  You could have a 3GHz processor with 128MB of RAM, in which case the RAM would be the winner or you could have a 1.5GHz processor with 4GB of RAM in which case extra RAM is less useful...  Also type of CPU and RAM is important.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what it currently has in it and what it is being used for. 
But to generalize RAM will probably give you the best performance to cost benefit. This is because if your processes are IO bound due to memory swapping more CPU cycles will do absolutely nothing to improve the situation.